# Table of contents in render markdown by shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have problems generating table of contents in the markdown generated by my shinyapp.
I have tried to set in the YAML toc = TRUE but it doesn't work.

the app is something like this, an interface where some data is uploaded and a markdown where some graphics are rendered.

the problem is that when generating the pdf, html or word the table of contents is not generated.

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(qcc)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

shinyApp(ui =
           fluidPage(fileInput("file", "Cargar Datos", multiple = FALSE),
                     radioButtons('format', 'Formato del documento', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),inline = TRUE),                                           
                      downloadButton('downloadReport')),
         
         server = function(input, output, session){
           
                 
           myData <- reactive({ infile <- input$file
           if(is.null(infile)) return(NULL)
           data   <- read_excel(infile$datapath)
           data}) 
           
        plotData <- function(){plot(myData}
           
           output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
             filename = function() {
               paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
                 input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
               ))
             },
             
             content = function(file) {
               src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
               
               # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
               # permission to the current working directory
               owd <- setwd(tempdir())
               on.exit(setwd(owd))
               file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
               
               library(rmarkdown)
               out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
                 input$format,
                 PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
               ))
               file.rename(out, file)
             }
           )
           
           ########################################
           
           
        ####   
         })
```

report.Rmd

````
---
title: "title"
subtitle: "subtitle"
output: 
    toc: true 
    toc_depth: 4  
    number_sections: true 
author:  
- "a1"
- "a2"
     
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
params:
    p1: "p1"
    p2: "p2"
    
---

# section1
## section1.1
# section2

```{r}
plotData()
````

Comment: Try passing the options as arguments to the rendering function, e.g. `rmarkdown::render('report.Rmd', rmarkdown::pdf_document(toc = TRUE, toc_depth = 4, number_sections = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try passing the options as arguments to the rendering function, e.g.
>
> ```
> rmarkdown::render('report.Rmd', rmarkdown::pdf_document(toc = TRUE, toc_depth = 4, number_sections = TRUE))
> ```

answered by [stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572062/table-of-contents-in-render-markdown-by-shinyapp/63909978#comment112415975_63572062) on the question.